# How to call an array from a static method?

Tags: arrays, static

In this code, how do I call an array globally for other methods to use?

Background info on my code, we are asked to scan a file that contains DNA strands then translating it to an RNA Strand.

I receive the **error: " cannot find symbol -  variable dna "**  when i call the dna array on the translation method (it can't find dna.length) `for(int i=0; i < dna.length; i++){`

```
public class FileScannerExample 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //This is how to create a scanner to read a file

        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("dnaFile.txt"));  
        String dnaSequence = inFile.next();
        int dnalength = dnaSequence.length();

        String[] dna = new String[dnalength];

        for(int i=0; i<=dna.length-2 ; i++)
        {
            dna[i]=dnaSequence.substring(i,i+1); //looking ahead and taking each character and placing it in the array 
        }

        dna[dna.length-1]=dnaSequence.substring(dna.length-1); //reading the last spot in order to put it in the array 

        //Testing that the array is identical to the string
        System.out.println(dnaSequence);
        for(int i = 0 ; i<=dna.length-1; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(dna[i]);
        }

    }



    public void  translation()
    {  
        for(int i=0; i < dna.length; i++){
            //store temporary 
            if (dna[i] = "A"){
                dna[i] = "U"; 
            }
            if(dna[i] = "T"){
                dna[i] = "A";
            }
            if(dna[i] = "G"){
                dna[i]= "C"; 
            }
            if(dna[i] = "C"){
                dna[i] = "G";
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to bring the symbol into scope before you can reference it. you can do this, either by pulling it up into a higher scope (as a field in the class), or by sending it into the local scope by passing it as a method parameter.

As a class member:

```
public class Test
{
    private String myField;

    void A() {
        myField = "I can see you";
    }

    void B() {
        myField = "I can see you too";
    }
}
```

As a method parameter:

```
public class Test
{
    void A() {
        String myVar = "I can see you";
        System.out.println(myVar);
        B(myVar);
    }

    void B(String param) {
        param += " too";
        System.out.println(param);
    }
}
```

Note that in order to see an instance member, you must be referencing it from a non-static context. You can get around this by declaring the field as static too, although you want to be careful with static state in a class, it generally makes the code more messy and harder to work with.

Comment: Thank you! the method parameter helped a lot